# openbox autostart only works partially

Tags: scripting, openbox, autostart

I'm new to openbox but have already found great appreciation in using it. I've however got some troubles with my autostart file.
My `~/.config/openbox/autostart` looks like:

```
  tint2
  dbus-launch xfce4-power-manager
  dbus-launch nm-applet
  feh --bg-fill ~/Pictures/wallpaper/Matrix-Wallpaper-001.jpg
```

and while tint2 starts properly, none of the other commands get executed.
For troubleshooting I shrank it to:

```
  tint2
  xfce4-power-manager
  nm-applet
```

but still, only tint2... can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1):

You should run the commands in background, otherwise the next'll wait until the previous command has finished.

To run a shell command in background just attach `&` – like that:

```
tint2 &
dbus-launch xfce4-power-manager &
dbus-launch nm-applet &
feh --bg-fill ~/Pictures/wallpaper/Matrix-Wallpaper-001.jpg &
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been pointed out on the openbox wiki [Help:Autostart](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart) page:

> ```
> # Programs that will run after Openbox has started
>
> # Set the wallpaper
> hsetroot ~/wallpaper.png &
>
> # Run a Composite manager
> xcompmgr -c -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55 &
>
> # SCIM support (for typing non-english characters)
> scim -d &
>
> # A panel for good times
> fbpanel &
> ```
>
> To run commands for all users system-wide, place them in a similar
>   file in /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart.
>
> Make sure that you end any commands with **"&"** so that they are run in
>   the background, **or any programs after it will not run**.